# How can I use break and continue in Django templates?

Tags: python, django

I want to put break and continue in my code, but it doesn't work in Django template. How can I use continue and break using Django template for loop. Here is an example:

```
{% for i in i_range %}
{% for frequency in patient_meds.frequency %}
{% ifequal frequency i %}
<td class="nopad"><input type="checkbox" name="frequency-1" value="{{ i }}" checked/> {{ i }} AM</td>
{{ forloop.parentloop|continue }} ////// It doesn't work
{ continue }                      ////// It also doesn't work
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor%}
<td class="nopad"><input type="checkbox" name="frequency-1" value="{{ i }}"/> {{ i }} AM</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to be clearer. Is this a python problem or a django template problem? Normally templates shouldn't have such logic in them. Can you post a simple example with some code?

Comment: You will have to show us the code that does not work and explain how it fails (for example by copying the exact error message into your question).

Comment: % for i in i_range %} {% for frequency in patient_meds.frequency %} {% ifequal frequency i %} {{ i }} AM {{ forloop.parentloop|continue }} ////// I does'nt work { continue } ////// It also does'nt work {% endifequal %} {% endfor%} {{ i }} AM {% endfor %}

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For-loops in Django templates are different from plain Python for-loops, so `continue` and `break` will not work in them. See for yourself in the Django [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), there are no `break` or `continue` template tags. Given the overall position of Keep-It-Simple-Stupid in Django template syntax, you will probably have to find another way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: thats true, but it's like limitation, not KISS. break is simple.
example: stop iterate main loop if any nested loop produce enough items - very usefull and simple with break in template - neat template system like mako or cheetah have support for break/continue.

Comment: @ups in the example you've given you could simply use the template tag `slice` (example: `list|slice:":10"`) to limit the loop to a certain number of iterations, or even do it at the context level.

Answer (score 40):

Django doesn't support it naturally.

You can implement forloop|continue and forloop|break with custom filters.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/

Comment: That's a LOT more code than I expected for implementing continue and break.

Answer (score 16):

For most of cases there is no need for custom templatetags, it's easy:

**continue**:

```
{% for each in iterable %}
  {% if conditions_for_continue %}
       <!-- continue -->
  {% else %}
       ... code ..
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**break** use the same idea, but with the wider scope:

```
{% set stop_loop="" %}
{% for each in iterable %}
  {% if stop_loop %}{% else %}
       ... code ..
       under some condition {% set stop_loop="true" %}
       ... code ..
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

This is Jinja template, which you can easily use within Django b/c Jinja is built in.

You can use even both template backends in the same project (Jinja and Django template).

Comment: This is Jinja templating.

Comment: There is no `set` command in django template.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a continue/break after certain conditions, I use the following Simple Tag as follows with "Vanilla" Django 3.2.5:

```
@register.simple_tag
def define(val=None):
  return val
```

Then you can use it as any variable in the template

```
{% define True as continue %}
      
{% for u in queryset  %}

  {% if continue %}

    {% if u.status.description == 'Passed' %}
      <td>Passed</td>
      
      {% define False as continue %}

    {% endif %}

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Extremely useful for any type of variable you want to re-use on template without using `with` statements.