# How to break "for loop" after 1 iteration in Django template

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have this code

```
    {% for account in object_list %}
        <tr>
        {% for field, value in book.get_fields %}
              <th>{{ field.verbose_name }}</th> 
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {{ break }}
    {% endfor %}
```

I want to break the for loop after first iteration. break is not working

Comment: Why use a loop if you want to stop after the first iteration? Use `{% with account=object_list|first %} ... {% endwith %}`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397470/for-loop-iteration-in-django

Comment: the title of this question is misleading, it should include the "after 1 iteration" bit.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no `break` in Django template system. Django template system is not programmed with **python** but [with its own language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/).

Depending on what you need to do, you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992230/django-for-loop-counter-break) useful. Otherwise, just put the **one and only account** you are trying to print on **HTML** on a special field on your `RequestContext`.

Answer (score 125):

I think you should use slice to achieve your goal

```
{% for account in object_list|slice:":1" %}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't use break statement but you can choose not to print them on html. It's not a best solution but you can use it. I use the following one;

```
{%for tumbnail in image %}
         {%if tumbnail.object_id == element.id %}
          <img src="/media/{{ tumbnail.image }}" class="tr_all_hover"alt="">

{{ "<!--" }}
  {%endif%} 
{%endfor%}     
{{ "-->" }}
```

Its basicly seem like this on browser.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPbR3.jpg

Comment: Quite clever!  And quite helpful!

Answer (score 5):

```
     {% for i in list %}
      {% if forloop.counter < 11 %}                                     
        <tr>
          <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.product__name }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.brand__name }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.country__name}}</td> 
          <td>{{ i.city__name}}</td>  
                     
        </tr>
      {% endif %} 
             
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you use filterset, slicing method result in problem. Most simple and effective way is this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your Django template system for loop in javascript for loop as inner loop and can use break as follows :-

```
for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
        {% for owner in Owner %}
            id  = "{{owner.id}}";
            if(id == pk1){
                f="{{owner.flat}}";
                break;
            }             
        {% endfor %}
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this with a condition.  It's ugly and hacky, but it works (for me).  `first` is what the OP wanted, but this answers the actual question more closely.

Given this:

```
obj = {
  'children': [
    { 'possessions' : { 'toys': [] } },
    { 'possessions' : { 'toys': ['train'] } }
    { 'possessions' : { 'toys': ['train', 'ball'] } }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to know if my obj has any children with possessions that are toys.

## Here's what I did:

#### Python Equivalent:

```
if ([child for child in obj.children if child.possessions.toys]):
  # Whatever
```

#### Django Template:

My approach was to use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to build sets of candidates which did or didn't match the criteria:

```
{% regroup obj.children by possessions.toys|length_is:"0" as by_toys %}
{% for check in by_toys %}{% if check.grouper == False %}
  Whatever
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

`regroup` builds a new object that is essentially:

```
[
  { 'grouper': '', 'list': [/*...*/] },
  { 'grouper': True, 'list': [/*...*/] },
  { 'grouper': False, 'list': [/*...*/] }
]
```

The `length_is:"0"` makes sure that we have at most three elements in that list and the `grouper` is either `True` or `False` or `''`.  Then we iterate over the list and check for a `False` value.

- If there are no children it'd be an empty list and the `if` would never be hit.
- If no children have toys, it'd be a list without a `False` `grouper`.
- If all children have toys, it'd be a list with a `False` `grouper`.
- If some children have toys, it'd be a list with `False` and `True` `grouper`s.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can check if forloop.counter == 1 or if forloop.first and simply print that first item.

```
  {% for account in object_list %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <tr>
        {% for field, value in book.get_fields %}
              <th>{{ field.verbose_name }}</th> 
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `break` in Django template system but you can achieve an statement like break with bellow architecture. (Loop will go iteration but u don't do anything.)

1- Use with to define a variable to determine current status,

2- Use a template custom tag to change statement to negate current status.

in template use like this:

```
{% with statement=1 %}
   {% for obj in listObject %}
       {% if ifStatement and statement %}
           {% changeStatement statement as statement %} // when u don't want to enter in if again.
           Do your job here!!
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

In template custom tags :

```
@register.simple_tag
def changeStatement(status):
    return not status
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing is the best as mentioned on top!

Alternatively, you can use a template variable for more complex continue/breaks:

[How can I use break and continue in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921027/how-can-i-use-break-and-continue-in-django-templates/69837466#69837466)