# Breaking out of a for loop from a nested if statement in Django

Tags: django

is there a way to break out of this `for` loop from inside the `if` statement. Currently our database is incorrectly storing multiple primary phones and I would like to break out of the for loop after the first primary phone is found. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
{% for phone in user_phones %}
    {% if phone.primary %}
        <div>{% if phone.type %}{{ phone.type|title }}: {% endif %}<span itemprop="telephone">{{ phone.phone_format }}</span></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Updated:**

Or just fail the `if` condition by creating a variable within the `if true` branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break "for loop" in Django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507817/how-to-break-for-loop-in-django-template)

Comment: This sounds more like business logic than a ui/template problem. I recommend preparing a specific context variable in your view.

Comment: @Wtower that question is not the same

Answer (score 2):

If you have to stay within the template layer you could use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

```
{% regroup user_phones|dictsort:"primary" by primary as phones_list %}

{% for phone in phones_list %}
    {% if phone.grouper %}
    {{ phone.list.0.type }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

**What it does**

`regroup` together with the [`dictsort`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort) filter (which also works on querysets) groups the instances in `user_phones` by the value of `primary`.

`regroup` will add an attribute named `grouper`, which when grouping by a `bool` (the value of `primary`) will either be `True` or `False`.

`for` then iterates over the variable `phones_list`, which is provided by `regroup`. Since we have sorted the results by `primary`, `{% if phone.grouper %}` will tell us when we hit the group of items with `primary == True`.

`regroup` packs the items that belong to a group into the attribute `list`. So the first item can be accessed with `phone.list.0.type`, `phone.list.0.phone_format`, etc.

***Note:***
if you need to access `foo.list.0` many times it can be assigned to a variable (using [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with)):

```
{% regroup user_phones|dictsort:"primary" by primary as phones_list %}

{% for items in phones_list %}
    {% if items.grouper %}
    {% with items.list.0 as phone %}
    <div>{% if phone.type %}{{ phone.type|title }}: {% endif %}<span itemprop="telephone">{{ phone.phone_format }}</span></div>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `break` in Django templates. You may handle it in your view by storing the `primary phone` that you are looking for to a variable and then calling it in your template.

Comment: So there's no way to do it `from inside the if statement`?

Comment: @Dusty: No, break is not possible in a Django template for loop. You'll have to process the data before passing it to the template.

Comment: @Dusty yes, there is no way. You should handle it in `views.py`.

Comment: Can you define variables in `for` loops in Django?

Comment: You cannot. You should do it in py file.