# Is there a break template tag in Django I can use

Tags: python, django

I am running a for loop to find an image, but I want to block the for loop after it has found an image.

I have found this website that seems to solve my problem but doesn't seem to be updated for Django 1.10.5: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/.

```
{% for article in object_list %}
    {% if article.get == true %}
        <div id="tagHeader" style="background: url({{ article.get_thumbnails|varkey:'grid_thumb' }}) no-repeat center center fixed;"><!-- background image not working becuase home_background isn't in CMS -->
    {% else %}
        <div id="tagHeader" style="background: url({% static 'publicnfx/images/baconburger.jpg' %}) no-repeat center center fixed;">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Does anyone know another solution for this?

Comment: Looks like something you should do in Python code.

Comment: I think I am going to have to, I am going to try one more solution using tags and if that works I will post it in here, if not I will resort to python.

Comment: You will find useful [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507817/how-to-break-for-loop-in-django-template).

Comment: My opinion is that logic should stay out from templates in Django.
Limit object_list at view level and your problem is solved.

Parse your file for background names and determine object_list length.

Comment: @KyrylHavrylenko for photos in gallery.photo_set|slice:":1" So I used this and it works. But if there is no image in the first image does this mean it will just return blank?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break "for loop" in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507817/how-to-break-for-loop-in-django-template)

Comment: @MaxLoyd yep. You need to filter your object_list in the view. Just filter it, store needed article in `article_with_image` and render it in template without any loops.

Answer (score 0):

By simply adding `|slice:":1"` to the end of the for loop I achieved the result I wanted. This stopped my for loop as soon as it grabbed the first image from the first article.

```
{% for article in object_list|slice:":1" %}
```