# How to break “for loop” in Django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, django-2.0

My code is:

```
{% for key, value in section.items %}
    {% for key_t, value_t in title.items %}
            {% if value_t.section_id == key|add:"0" %}
                 <li class="nav-item-header"><div class="text-uppercase font-size-xs line-height-xs"> 
                 {{value.title}}</div> <i class="icon-menu" title="Tables"></i></li>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to break the for loop when if the condition is true. like as

```
{% for key, value in section.items %}
    {% for key_t, value_t in title.items %}
            {% if value_t.section_id == key|add:"0" %}
                 <li class="nav-item-header"><div class="text-uppercase font-size-xs line-height-xs"> 
                 {{value.title}}</div> <i class="icon-menu" title="Tables"></i></li>
            {{break}}
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How is it possible? please help me...

Comment: Im having trouble understanding your iterations. can you explain what they are intended for?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to break out of a for loop in Django Template. However, you can achieve this by setting a variable and adding an if statement on the top like this.

```
{% set isBreak = False %}
{% for number in numbers %}
{% if 99 == number %}
    {% set isBreak = true %}
{% endif %}

{% if isBreak %}
    {# this is a comment. Do nothing. #}
{% else %}
    <div>{{number}}</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

for some additional help check out this link
https://dev.to/anuragrana/for-loops-in-django-2jdi
or check this answer on stack overflow
[How to break "for loop" in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507817/how-to-break-for-loop-in-django-template)

Comment: But Django doesn't have a "set" tag... at least it says it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Your answer is false. There is no `set` tag in django template.

Comment: There is no set tag in Django templates, as has been said by other users, if you have a way of implementing set in django templates please include that in this answer.